# Make "property" countable as theorem or lemma

Tags: hyperref, ref

I need to reference some text in a itemized list.

If I label the item and then referencing it, will appear in the result document a link to the closest section.

If I label the item and then "namereferencing" it, will appear the correct name but in the result document click on it will bring me at start of the document.

How can I correct reference an item? and a simple text?

Comment: Hello! You should add a MWE (minimal working example) to your question, so that it may be easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please provide more information about what "If I label the item" entails. E.g., are you using `itemize` or `enumerate` lists? How are these lists numbered? Do you use any packages -- e.g., `enumitem`-- to help manage the appearance of lists?

Comment: Use `\phantomsection` to set an anchor for the hyperref link.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item\label{it:item} I am an item
    \end{enumerate}
    \lipsum 
    As stated in the item \ref{it:item}.
\end{document}
```

If I click on the reference it brings me straight to the item. I hope I understood your question, though.